# Spring Integration logging with sensitive information

Tags: spring-integration

I recently add si to my project and have been very happy with it. I'm having an issue with my logging. I am using logback and all works ok; however, I have sensitive information flowing through the system that cannot be logged "as is". Certain data must be intercepted and masked before logging. If I configure my log level below WARN then I see this sensitive info. What is the best way to filter all messages bound for logging?  I am using a inbound gateway with a service activator for an si server. I am using an async outbound gateway for an si client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear how the `logging` is relevant to the Spring Integration.

Seems for me it's enough to write some custom `Appender` accodrding to your logging framework.

From other side you can `filter` messages before log them using SI `<filter>` and `<logging-channel-adapter>` after `<filter>`.

But in this case you can't use `logger.debug()` (or similar) from your code: you alway should send the message to the `channel` for logging.

Please, explain further from where and how you want to filter (or mask) logging messages.

Comment: I think you just answered it, logging isn't relevant to si. I tried adding a interceptor on the channels to do the masking which did work, but it complicates the my security review to have a log level with a comment next to it saying "Never put to DEDUG" :). I will explore extending the logback Appender. Good idea, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `logback` and `slf4j` I used this to mask the si messages...

```
public class LoggingFilter extends TurboFilter {
    private static final Marker secured = MarkerFactory.getMarker("secured");

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Marker marker, Logger logger, Level level, String format, Object[] params, Throwable t) {
        if (format != null && logger.getName().startsWith("org.springframework.integration")) {
            boolean isSecured = marker != null && (marker.equals(secured) || marker.contains(secured));
            if (isSecured) {
                return NEUTRAL;
            } else {
                if (marker == null) {
                    marker = secured;
                } else {
                    marker.add(secured);
                }
                String message = MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(format, params).getMessage();
                //TODO: mask message here.
                logger.log(marker, logger.getName(), toLocationAwareLoggerInteger(level), message, null, t);
                return DENY;
            }
        } else {
            return NEUTRAL;
        }
    }
}
```